# Binding doesn't work for custom UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF-UserControl-Library with 'custom' controls which I want to use in a WPF-Application:

InputBox.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControls.BaseControls.InputBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Name="BaseInputBox">
    <Grid>
        <Border CornerRadius="10,0,10,0"
                BorderThickness="1"
                BorderBrush="{Binding ElementName=BaseInputBox, Path=InputColor}">
            <TextBox BorderThickness="0"
                     Background="Transparent"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                     Text="{Binding ElementName=BaseInputBox, Path=InputValue}" />
        </Border>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

InputBox.xaml.cs

```
namespace UserControls.BaseControls
{

    public partial class InputBox
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty InputColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("InputColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(InputBox), null);
        public static readonly DependencyProperty InputValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("InputValue", typeof(string), typeof(InputBox), null);

        public InputBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string InputValue
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(InputBox.InputValueProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(InputBox.InputValueProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public Brush InputColor
        {
            get
            {
                return (Brush)GetValue(InputBox.InputColorProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(InputBox.InputColorProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want the ability to set the border's borderbrushColor and textbox' text in a WPF-Application...

MainWindow.xaml (independent project which references my UserControl-Library)

```
<Window x:Class="DK.MathQuest.UI.WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:UCs="clr-namespace:UserControls.BaseControls;assembly=UserControls">

    <DockPanel>
        <UCs:InputBox InputValue="{Binding DataContext.Testbind, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      InputColor="Aqua"
                      Width="200"
                      Height="100"
                      DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                      KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
   private readonly FooViewModel _viewModel;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new FooViewModel();
            _viewModel = (FooViewModel )DataContext;
        }


        private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Enter))
            {
                var input = (sender as InputBox).InputValue;
                _viewModel.Testbind= input;
            }
        }
```

If I set my Testbind property in my ViewModel the InputBox is empty. If I write something in my InputBox and press enter, InputValue is null.
So there is a binding error but I don't know where or what my mistake is.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Change your TextBox-Binding to `Text="{Binding ElementName=BaseInputBox, Path=InputValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`. That should fix it

Comment: my ViewModel gets the InputBox' value as I want. But If I change the property in my ViewModel itself, but my InputBox' isn't updated...

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Have you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Please change the textbox in user control to below           mentioned :

     <TextBox BorderThickness="0"
                 Background="Transparent"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                 Text="{Binding  InputValue, RelativeSource                 AncestorType=UserControl, Mode=FindAncestor}, UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}  />

   Because InputValue property is in UserControl you have to bind it to input value on UserControl and it will work.
```

Also you need to implement InotifyPropertyChanged in viewmodel

Answer (score -2):

It sholud work if remove the readonly declaration of FooViewModel object as like below.
private FooViewModel _viewModel;

Comment: Without a good [mcve], it's impossible to know for sure what the bug is. But _for sure_, it has nothing to do with the `_viewModel` field being `readonly`, or even with it being `private`.